# editing is disabled in UITextfield in a static TableView - iOS 6.0 only

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield, ios6

I have two UITextFields inside a static TableView (in a Storyboard) for loggin in. The first time go to the tableView via a modal segue, the TextFields are editable as they should be. When I then go back and forth to that view again, the TextField seem to be non-editable. If I read out the `textField.isEnabled`, it is set to YES. 
Even more strange: this behavior is only with iOS 6.0. On iOS 5.0 everything is fine.

I've already added this in viewWillAppear
TextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

I've also commented out all of my viewDidLoad and viewWillAppearCode, but still no avail.

Any idea is welcome.

[image]

EDIT: after closing and restarting the app, I once again have one shot. I looks like something is screwed, once I opened and closed the view.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a very similar problem with my TextFields in one view not being editable after doing a back and forth segue with another view.  For me, it was a problem with the first responder status, and things started working fine after adding the following in prepareForSegue:

```
[self.textFieldName1 resignFirstResponder];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, thats a good idea. Looks like it didn't help here on the first run, but I'll give it another run.